# connecting both hive & cassandra to presto at same time

Tags: presto

Is there any possible way to connect both hive & cassandra at same time if I have the same database name.?
I need to access the tables that are in hive databse & cassandra keyspace in the same time..

Thanks & regards
Pavan Chakravarthy

Comment: Using what technologies?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure both catalogs in etc/catalog folder and query them using two different queries or use a join to fetch them 
As we can provide **catalog_name.db_name.table_name** to access a table.